# Docker: unable to pull images

Tags: docker

I have a CentOS 7.2 server (running in VMWare) in which I would like to pull some docker images but getting the following error:

```
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
Pulling repository docker.io/library/ubuntu
docker: Network timed out while trying to connect to https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubuntu/images. You may want to check your internet connection or if you are behind a proxy..
```

But when I run `curl -I https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubuntu/images` I get reply (which I think is strange):

```
01:41:33-myserv ~$ curl -I https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubuntu/images
HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established

HTTP/1.1 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Sat, 29 Oct 2016 23:43:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Allow: GET, PUT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

I am behind a proxy and have configured it in `/etc/sysconfig/docker`:

```
HTTP_PROXY='http://123.345.67.89:3128'
HTTPS_PROXY='https://123.345.67.89:3128'
```

I also tested with openssl, not able to establish connection to index.docker.io, running the `openssl s_client -connect docker.io:443` just hangs.

Restarted and reloaded. Cannot pull images. Any hints?

**Update**

Environment:

```
21:58:07-myserv ~$ env  | grep proxy
http_proxy=http://123.345.67.89:3128/
ftp_proxy=http://123.345.67.89:3128/
rsync_proxy=http://123.345.67.89:3128/
https_proxy=http://123.345.67.89:3128/
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com
21:58:19-myserv ~$
```

Comment: I am confused; you said you're behind a proxy server, but you were apparently able to use `curl` to connect directly.  Or do you have environment variables in place such that curl would use the proxy?  If you require a proxy for outside access, I would expect your `openssl s_client` example to fail, since it is attempting a direction. Would you expect different behavior? Can you update your question to help clarify some of these details?

Comment: @larsks yes, I am confused too. I have greped proxy in my environmental variables and updated the question. There are env variables that define proxy. These proxy settings are the same as the one I defined for docker. I don't know why openssl example does not fail. I also tested openssl to check if it is able to connect to corporate web site and openssl connection succeeds to that website.